# Thrift server access unserialized data

Tags: thrift

Is it possible that thrift server does not unserialize message, but it will give access to that data so i can save it and get for later send?
To be precise.
I have IDL and service such that

```
void sendStructA(StructA)

struct StructA
{
  1:  string string_thing,
  4:  byte   byte_thing,
  9:  i32    i32_thing,
  11: i64    i64_thing
}
```

and have client and server generated.. server has interface so i have in code on server side

```
void sendStructA(StructA s)
{
      // do something
}
```

but i dont want `s` of type StructA. I need to catch that struct before its unserialized to StructA. And i.e TJSON protocol is chosen. It should give me access to that json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because Thrift is an **RPC and Serialization framework**. There are a few examples in the code, look for "serializer". The basic idea is to set up a stream transport or similar and `protocol.Write()` and `protocol.Read()` into and from that stream, like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375645/apache-thrift-translate-this-code-from-java-to-php-serialization-of-an-object).

What you do with the data before and after is completely up to you. For example, you could send the data to a server, or process it, or just throw it away.

Comment: I know that it is possible by TSerializer class but, its hard to catch that when server is builded from protocol, processor etc.  I have found your old answer on my old question that was quite similar:) And your answer was TapProtocol. To be precise. I need communication between client and server i.e by Tcp and then server should not give me unserialized data but raw data.. i.e if ive choose TJSONProtocol. It will give me json

Comment: "*I have found your old answer on my old question that was quite similar*" => close as duplicate?

Comment: I need to check that. I wonder if there is solution to use maybe custom processor to catch that earlier. `Tap` sounds like duplication. And I am not sure if it exists in Java